# Is there a publicly available list of known good GS1-128 codes for testing?

Tags: barcode, datamatrix, gs1-ai-syntax, gs1-128

I just finished writing a function to interpret GS1-128 codes (the data, not the barcode/datamatrix image) in (hopefully) any constellation they can come in.
I am now trying to thoroughly test the function.
All manually generated codes I have tried are working fine (first try, obviously), but generating error free GS1-128 codes by hand is a rather slow process and also flawed methodology since my understanding of creating a norm-conform code and my functions logic are obviously the same, but not nessccessarily correct.

I have already inquired at the local GS1 organization whether they have a list of known-good codes for testing they are allowed to hand out. The answer was no.
I have also searched on the internet for either a list or an automated means of generating codes (preferably with varried contents and orders od content) in bulk, neither yielded a helpful result.

I don't really know of any better place to ask this quiestion, so I'm asking this community, since I have the hope that someone might have one either lying around or has means of generating a reasonable (or unreasonable) amount of codes (the data, not the barcode/datamatrix image (although that would work just as well)) without too much effort.

If it's available I'd gladly take a list with decoded contents per code to further automate and scale up the testing, but I'm really not going to turn anything down :P

Hope whoever read this far is having a good day.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you take a look at the unit tests in the GS1 Barcode Syntax Engine, which comprehensively processes GS1 AI syntax messages:

https://github.com/gs1/gs1-syntax-engine/blob/main/src/c-lib/ai.c#L795

It's a shame that your GS1 Member Organisation were unable to refer you to their own tool.

Comment: I have nothing left to say but thank you.
For evey one else looking at this: Check lines 1012 and onward.